# factory_girl undefined method `save!' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, factory-bot

```
## app/models/armor_type.rb
class ArmorType < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
...
end

## spec/models/armor_type_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe ArmorType, type: :model do
  it "has a valid name" do
    armor_type = create(:armor_type)
  end
end

## spec/factories/armor_types.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :armor_type do
    name "cloth"
  end
end

## spec/support/factory_girl.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end

## spec/rails_helper.rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if     Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'support/factory_girl'
require 'capybara/rspec'

## Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

I can't seem to get factory_girl to work properly. I created at testApp using a SQLite3 test database and it worked, however using my current application which uses a PostgreSQL test database I get the following error;

```
          1) ArmorType has a valid name
             Failure/Error: armor_type = create(:armor_type)
             NoMethodError:
               undefined method `save!' for #<ArmorType:0x000000071a8b58 @name="cloth">
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:14:in `block in initialize'
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `[]'
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `create'
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
             # ./.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
             # ./.bundle/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
             # ./spec/models/armor_type_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
             # .bundle/binstubs/rspec:16:in `load'
             # .bundle/binstubs/rspec:16:in `<main>'
```

I've gone ahead and created another test app using a PostgreSQL test database and I get the same errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: This wont fix anything, but on validations maybe you should be doing them on non persisted records?  Regarding the `save!` that is really strange. could you paster your armor type factory for a bit more info?

Comment: Do you actually _build_ a factory? As in: do you have a dir spec/factories with a file `armor_types.rb` and a `FactoryGirl.define do ...` ?
Also, I am not sure about the `require 'support/factory_girl'` in your rails_helper. AFAIK, it should refer to the gem Factory_girl. And the third thing to check: did you install the FactoryGirl for _rails_ gem? There are 2 of them, 1 especially for rails.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the factory (silly misake, sorry) and the Gemfile.

Comment: @Mauddev The 'support/factory_girl' is per https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: The way you use it, I can't find it in the link.  Maybe read my comment again (about the `rails_helper`. Also, in your Factory definition as you post it here, there's missing an `end`.

Comment: @Mauddev I'm not sure I understand your recommendation, I am sorry. I did fix the posted Factory, just a mistype here on stack, not in the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had inadvertently created a file 'armor_type.rb" in the very early stages of testing, resulting in this error. It was not related to factory_girl, nor rspec.

## newbiemistakes